# mqsisetdbparms not working with special characters

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I've been working on a message flow on IBM Integration Bus just for my studies where I wanted to use the Loopback Request Node to connect with MongoDB Atlas. I created a userID "iibUser" and set the password to "iibP@$$w0rd".
Next, I wanted to set the params using ***mqsisetdbparms WBIBKD12 -n loopback::secID -u iibUser -p iibP@$$w0rd*** but after ***mqsireportdbparms WBIBKD12 -n***, it is not showing in the report, check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV9ri.png). Although it worked fine for password without any special character.

Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Comment: Are you running that on unix or linux?  vs Windows.

Comment: The screen shot is in windows and appears to have worked.  I see iibUser is displayed.

Comment: @JoshMc I'm running on Windows, the iibUser which is displayed has resource name "loopback::secid" which is the resource I added with different password. I was trying the resource "loopback::secID" with special character passwords.

Comment: I suggest you try with just the command `mqsisetdbparms WBIBKD12 -n loopback::secID -u iibUser -p`.  Leave the password off.  Once you do this the command will prompt you twice to enter the password.  See of this lets you enter the password with the special characters, if this works I'll put a quick answer to this question for you to accept. If that doesn't work, are you sure that the resource name is case sensitive, if you try with `-n loopback::secID2` for example does it make a difference.  As far as I can tell the `@`, `$`, and `0` should have no special meaning to the `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Hello, I never had any issue with special character on Unix and mqsisetdbparms, but I had to escape special character multiple time. I am not that familiar with Windows, but maybe you need to escape a few character (in shell you always put "" or '' around the values to avoid that issue, that might also work in windows)

Comment: I found the issue. I already had an entry with "loopback::secid" and I was trying to enter "loopback::secID".
I expected it to be case sensitive however it seems it's not. I tried "mqsisetdbparms WBIBKD12 -n loopback::mysecid -u iibUser" and it worked. Thanks a lot everyone for your time and responses.